# CSS Transition No jQuery; Display then Hide

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I built a card game where upon clicking a button the display will either be "Correct!" or "Wrong!"  I would like the display to flash and then go away after a couple second but not rearrange the content below it, which in this case is the #winStreak and #longestStreak.  I do not want to use jQuery.  I have tried adding transitions to CSS, but that does not seem to work.

HTML:

```
<p id="displayResult"></p>
<p id="winStreak"></p>
<p id="longestStreak"></p>
```

CSS:

```
#displayResult {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let foldButton = document.getElementById("foldBTN")
foldButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (!table[position].includes(completeHand) && !table[position].includes(completeHand2)) {
    document.getElementById("displayResult").innerHTML = "Correct!";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might use CSS `animation`:

```js
var result = document.getElementById('displayResult');

result.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  result.classList.remove('flashit');
});

let foldButton = document.getElementById('foldBTN');
foldButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result.innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  result.classList.add('flashit');
});
```

```css
#displayResult {
  font-size:3rem;
  height: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
}

#displayResult.flashit {
  animation: flashit 3s;
}

@keyframes flashit {
  5% {opacity:.5}
  10% {opacity:1}
  15% {opacity:.2}
  20% {opacity:1}
  40% {opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<div id="displayResult"></div>
<button id="foldBTN">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: I changed the CSS to this, but it works, and thanks!

#displayResult {
  color: #03699B;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
}

#displayResult.flashit {
  animation: flashit 1.5s;
}

@keyframes flashit {
 0% { opacity: 1; } 
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}